# RegEx for replacing alphanumeric chars in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, preg-replace

I want to upgrade a project from one version to another so, that in need to change thousands of lines with same pattern.

Example:

From this

```
 $this->returnData['status']
```

To this

```
$this->{returnData['status']}
```

By using following regex i found all the matches but  unable to replace with braces.

```
->[a-zA-z]{5,15}\['[a-zA-z]{5,15}'\]
```

I used following to replace

```
->\{[a-zA-z]{5,15}\['[a-zA-z]{5,15}'\]\}
```

Comment: Be carefull, `A-z` matches more than letters, have a look at an ASCII table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \$this->([A-Za-z]{5,15}\['[A-Za-z]{5,15}'\])
Replace: $this->{$1}
```

### Demo

The regex matches says to:

```
\$this->             match "$this->"
(                    then match and capture
    [A-Za-z]{5,15}   5-15 letters
    \[               [
    '[A-Za-z]{5,15}' 5-15 letters in single quotes
    \]               ]
 )                   stop capture group
```

The replacement is just `$this->` followed by the first capture group, but now wrapped in curly braces.

If you want to just match the arrow operator, regardless of what precedes it, then just use this pattern, and keep everything else the same:

```
->([A-Za-z]{5,15}\['[A-Za-z]{5,15}'\])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, I need to regex for this pattern ->[a-zA-z]{5,15}\['[a-zA-z]{5,15}'\]. $this is not constant

Comment: You never finished your comment :-(

Comment: I updated my answer.  If `$this` is not constant, then you should have made it more clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use negated character classes and use `\K` to forget the match. In the replacement use `$0` to insert the full match surrounded by `{` and `}`

Match:

```
->\K[^[\n]+\['[^\n']+']
```

That will match

- `->` match ->
- `\K` Forget what was matched
- `[^[\n]+` Match not [ or newline 1+ times or exactly `[a-zA-Z]{5,15}` instead of `[^[\n]+`
- `\[` Match `[`
- `'[^\n']+'` Match from ', 1+ times not ' or newline and then ' or exactly `[a-zA-Z]{5,15}` instead of `[^\n']+`
- `]` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LRBmzU/3)

Replace with:

```
{$0}
```

Result:

```
$this->{returnData['status']}
```

The exacter version would look like:

```
->\K[a-zA-Z]{5,15}\['[a-zA-Z]{5,15}']
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LRBmzU/2)

Note that `[a-zA-z]` [matches more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret) than `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Thanks its worked for me

Comment: You are welcome.